# View controllers's communication with swift

Tags: swift

I have two tabs so I have two view controllers,i need to update second tab from first view controller.Example:

User presses a button in first tab(so first view controller) then i have to update a label inside second tab.

I guess i have to call second view controller's method from first view controller.

What is the best to do this with swift ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a property in the one view controller to make it aware of the other one. In the referencing one declare

```
@IBOutlet weak var otherController:OtherViewController!
```

In your AppDelegate when all views are instantiated place the reference like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var referencingController: AController!
// ...
referencingController.otherController = otherController
```

Now you have the reference and you can use it in the referencing class like

```
otherController.doSomething()
```

Note the `!` in the above `var` declaration. This will automatically unwrap `otherController` on use.

Comment: Thank you,I will use this approach or notification center.Which do you suggest ?

Comment: The above is the direct way. I'd prefer it.

Comment: Can you explain more app delegate section ? Because I didn't understand exactly what should i put to app delegate

Comment: You need to drag an outlet from both views into you AppDelegate. Use them for putting the one into the other (assignment above)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve it.

1. Declare a delegate in first - add a method , and implement it in second
   (If you are sure that only one VC(2nd) needs to be updated upon click)
2. Use the Notification center to post the notification and observe that  from other VC. (If you think there can be many VCs which needs to be updated in the future).

Happy coding.